# How do I kill a Java application on Linux so that the shutdown hook is executed?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I'm using *Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-85-generic x86_64)*.

The application is launched with [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) and usually runs all the time. Up to know I used `kill` to stop it, but I'm not sure the shutdown hooks are executed that way.

How do I properly shut down the application so that the shutdown hooks are activated?

Comment: Why don't you try it? ( print something in your shutdown hook if you are not already logging something )

Comment: Because my logging mechanism stopped working and I'm still figuring out what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not kill you application using `kill -9 javaapp` instead use SIGTERM which is `kill -15 javaapp` See [this](https://dzone.com/articles/know-jvm-series-2-shutdown).